# Узнать, сколько чётных чисел между двумя числами

Tags: javascript

```
var i = 0
function B1(){
    var l = document.getElementById('inp1').value;
    var r = document.getElementById('inp2').value;
    var s = r - 1;

    if (l % 2 == 0){
        while (l < s){
            l += 2;
            i += 1;
        }
            }else{  
                while (l < s){
                    l += 3;
                    i += 1;
        }
    }
console.log('четных чисел', i)
}
```

Comment: `l += 3;` - ?? Создайте работающий пример с входными данными, добавьте ожидаемый ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не включая четные границы интервала:

```
if (l % 2 == 0)
  l++;
if (r % 2 == 0)
  r--;

var result = (r - l) / 2;
```

Comment: красавчик все работает, я понял твой код, он такой простой, а я затупил на ровном месте

Comment: @Aizel Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.